# How to nest routes using react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a settings page that is routed to `/admin/settings` and some pages from settings, for say `/admin/settings/objectives`. When I added a link in the settings page to `/admin/settings/objectives`it's changing the route to the specified address but the component doesn't change.

```
<Route exact path='/admin/settings' component={Settings} />
{/* Settings Route */}
<Route exact path='/admin/settings/objectives' component={Objective}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the

```
<Route exact path='/admin/settings/objectives' component={Objective}/>
```

one step up and after this route, put the first one( so reverse the order of your routes )

```
<Route exact path='/admin/settings' component={Settings} />enter code here
```

and don't put exact as attribute.

Comment: Actually fixed it with passing the route as the child components to the page instead of mentioning all on the App.js itself

Official Link: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/philosophy/nested-routes